# How to make an HTML web that allows a user to make a custom Pie Chart directly on the UI?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I found on Google Dev:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var arr = [];
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Answers', 'Number of answer'],
    ['template 1', 1],
    ['template 2', 2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Title of survey question'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="drawChart()">
  </form>
  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I want to create a form that allows users to input their data onto it and make their own pie chart. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

A google chart is based on **a google data table, which is an array of arrays**. You can loop through the groups of inputs on your page, and the individual inputs within those groups, to build the data table.

In this snippet, each group of related inputs is referred to as an *item*. Each item corresponds to a *row* on a table (and each of its related input values corresponds to a column or cell in the row.)

The code is based on [this Google Dev page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs).  See the in-code comments for further explanation.

```js
// Loads google resources and calls `googleIsReady` when done
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(googleIsReady);

// Main function has access to google resources
function googleIsReady(){
  const
    // Identifies some DOM elements
    itemDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("item"),
    makeChartBtn = document.getElementById("makeChartBtn"),
    pieChartDiv = document.getElementById("pieChartDiv"),

    // Defines google objects (and specifies where to show the chart)
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
    chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(pieChartDiv);

  // Calls assembleDataAndDrawChart when button is clicked
  makeChartBtn.addEventListener("click", assembleDataAndDrawChart);

  // Defines the click listener on the button
  function assembleDataAndDrawChart() {

    // Loops through `itemDivs` to populate `dataArray`
    const dataArray = [];
    for(let itemDiv of itemDivs){
      const
        // Gets the name and percentage inputs for this item
        itemInputsArray = Array.from(itemDiv.getElementsByTagName("input")),
        // Gets the inputs' values (converts percentage to a number)
        itemData = itemInputsArray.map(
          (input) => input.type == "number" // condition
            ? +input.value // if true, `+` converts to number
            : input.value // if false, keeps the string value
        );
      // Adds the `itemData` array as an item of `dataArray`
      dataArray.push(itemData);
    }

    // Draws the chart (or complains about invalid data)
    if(totalPercentageEquals100(dataArray)){
      drawChart(dataArray);
    }
    else{ alert("Pie charts must total 100%"); }
  }

  
  // Uses the google objects defined earlier to show the chart
  function drawChart(_dataArray){
    // (Column names are hard coded)
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');
    data.addRows(_dataArray);
    chart.draw(data, null); // Calls google's `.draw` method
  }

  //Returns true if data is valid
  function totalPercentageEquals100(_dataArray){
    let total = 0;
    for(let item of _dataArray){
      // Destructures each `item` array to bind values locally 
      [name, percentage] = item;
      if(name){ total += percentage; } // Adds up percentages
    }
    return (total == 100);
  }
}
```

```css
h1{ font-size: 14px; }
.item{ margin-bottom: 0.2em; }
input{ margin: 0 0.2em 0 0.1em; }
#makeChartBtn{ margin: 0.3em; }
#pieChartDiv{ width: 300px; height: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<h1>Enter Names and Percentages for up to 3 items</h1>
<div class="item">
  <label> Name<input class="name" value="Thing 1"/></label>
  <label> Percentage<input class="percentage" type="number" min="1" max="99" value="89"/></label>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <label>Name<input class="name" value="Thing 2"/></label>
  <label>Percentage<input class="percentage" type="number" min="1" max="99" value="11"/></label>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <label> Name<input class="name"/></label>
  <label> Percentage<input class="percentage" type="number" min="1" max="99"/></label>
</div>

<button id="makeChartBtn">Make chart</button>

<div id="pieChartDiv"></div>
```

Comment: An answer without explanation is often found to be not very useful and is therefore downvoted. Spoon-feeding answers to users who make no attempt of their own is also frowned upon, but more tolerated. Using `br` tags instead of CSS to make whitespace around a button is unconscionable :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I decided to try out that CSS thing everyone's talking about.